# Is it possible to have one page with multiple items, or 2 blogs on a site?

Tags: customization

I have a Page on my site that I use as a Blog.

And then there's another page that I'd like to add a few different posts to. It's not really a blog, it's a list of projects, and each one will have about 300 words of description.

I'd like users to be able to pick which project they want to view. So this could work as either a blog, or as a drop-down menu from the menu item 'other projects', or maybe in another way.

-- Since I already have a blog on the site, is it possible to add another blog under another menu item?

-- Or is there another way to accomplish the objective, such as making 'other projects' a drop-down menu?

The current blog is here: http://richardclunan.com/blog

And the page I'd like to list projects on is here: http://richardclunan.com/other-projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's absolutely possible on the same WordPress install.

How I do it, is I generally reserve the 'posts' sections for the site's news, and make a Custom Post Type for other things, such as your projects list.

Have a look at the [codex for custom post types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type), and the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png)

To separate the blog posts from your projects custom post type, simple add something like this is the appropriate template file:

```
 query_posts( 'post_type=projects' ); // For projects
```

Or

```
 query_posts( 'post_type=post' ); // For posts
```

query_posts works if you're using the main query.

---

Another solution, if you have no extra data to keep about projects, is to simply store your projects in 'posts' as well, and associate a category to them.

```
 query_posts( 'post_type=post&cat=5' ); //EX if category id 5 = projects category
```

Answer (score 1):

+1 for using custom post types and/or categories.

Another great resource for setting up Custom Post Types is: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/04/29/custom-post-types-in-wordpress

Justin Tadlock's tutorials, etc have helped me quite a bit while learning WordPress.

He explains how to create a new custom post type and how to retrieve data from it.